# How can I throttle the setState in React?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

1. there's a `SearchBar` component change the whole component state, then the `Whole` will re-render which leads to the child component `PlayerListWithQuery` to re-render with the new state as well.
2. there's a `PlayerListWithQuery` component query the `graphql` server base on the search content passed to this component

the problem is I don't wanna to execute the query too often but have to change the value of input instantly, how can I solve this issue.

```
import PlayerListWithQuery from './PlayerListWithQuery.js'
class Whole extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchContent: '',
    };
  }
  handleChange = val => {
    this.setState({
      searchContent: val,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar
          placeholder="Id"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.searchContent}
        />
        <PlayerListWithQuery searchContent={this.state.searchContent} {...this.props} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Whole;
```

// PlayerListWithQuery.js

```
const PlayerListWithQuery = graphql(QUERY_SINGLE_PLAYER, {
  options: props => ({
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    variables: {
      id: props.searchContent,
    },
  }),
})(PlayerList);

export default PlayerListWithQuery;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using [lodash's debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) for the same thing. Or you can implement a `debounce` function like this ([credit](https://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce))

```html
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
 var timeout;
 return function() {
  var context = this, args = arguments;
  var later = function() {
   timeout = null;
   if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
  };
  var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
  if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
 };
};
```

Comment: specific in my code, where can I put the debounce fn exactly? On one hand I wanna instant change the `value`, on the other hand I wanna debounced the re-render... , I am kind of lost

Comment: @Liuuil: I am not familiar with graphql, can you update the code of `PlayerList`? Or maybe take a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/mnylen/e944cd4e3255f4421a0b

Comment: Or this one: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/450#issuecomment-312427501

Comment: many thanks. in terms of component `Whole` itself, everytime the input value changed, the component will re-render, which leads to the child component re-render as well. Do you have a idea to solve this kind of thing?

Comment: You can use `shouldComponentUpdate` to check whether your child component should be re-rendered or not

Comment: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/450#issuecomment-292454453, the first paragraph of this comment, do you think he was wrong specially for `That way the input can rerender independently from the list` or there are something I don't know about react?

Comment: AFAIK, the child can either be independent or dependent based on your way of implementation, so that statement has no problem. You can `setState` your input value (belong to `state` of `SearchBar`), which in your case is `searchContent`. And use another value like `debouncedSearchContent` to pass to `PlayerListWithQuery`. That way your children is updated only when `setState({debouncedSearchContent})` is triggered.